# Destroying bookshelf/knex connection pool

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a db api that uses Bookshelf/Knex.

I have multiple Bookshelf models that look something like this:

```
import bookshelf from '../bookshelf';

var Product = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'product'
  // ...
});
export default Product;
```

The bookshelf include looks like :

```
import dbConfig from './dbConfig';

const knex = require('knex')(dbConfig);
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

module.exports = bookshelf;
```

I also have multiple api action calls that look something like this:

```
import Product from '../../Models/Product';

export default function getProducts(bookshelf) {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    Product.collection().fetch().then((products) => {
      resolve({
        products
      });
    });
  });
}
```

My problem is that knex pools connections and I need to destroy the connection pool before I resolve the request in the action files. However, in order to do that I need access to the bookshelf or knex objects which are imported in the model.

I can't think of a neat way of doing this. I could create the knex object in the top level file that calls the action, and then that process could destroy the connections when it receives the response. But then I would have to pass it to the actions and then to the models.  How can I do this so that the connection pool is destroyed without having to pass the knex object around everywhere?

Comment: Can you please share how did you fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up against this once and solved it by exporting the knex object as a property of the bookshelf export (i.e. add the line `module.exports.knex = knex;` to the bottom of your bookshelf include). That way, you can access is elsewhere by using `bookshelf.knex.destroy()`. It can also be handy for occasions where bookshelf doesn't implement some query that you need to make (e.g. `bookshelf.knex.raw('Some unsupported SQL query')`).

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://zetcode.com/javascript/bookshelf/) shows how to use `knex.destroy()` on APIs importing bookshelf.

On the bookshelf:

> module.exports.knex = knex;

On the API calling bookshelf:

```js
const knex = require('./bookshelf').knex; 
...
Product.collection().fetch()
.then((products) => {
      resolve({
        products
      });})
.finally(() => { knex.destroy(); });
```